# Google Maps for Rails - update markers with AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I am working on a web app and I use Ruby on Rails. Our index is made of a map and of a search field. You can search a location and the map updates its markers.

I would like to use Ajax to avoid refreshing the page. So I added `remote: true` to the form, a `respond_to` in the controller and a new `search.js.erb.` My `search.js.erb` renders a partial `_googlemap.erb` which contains the script to initialize the map.

Here is my problem. As the map already exists, it's like if I wanted to create the same object twice, which of course doesn't work and is awfull. I'd like to update only markers in the map with new ones. But I can't find a way to do it.

I saw the former version of Gmaps4rails integrated a way to do it ( `Gmaps.map.replaceMarkers(your_markers_json_array);` ) but it doesn't seem to work now. When I use it, I got this error: "`TypeError: Gmaps.map is undefined`". I tried with "`handler.replaceMarkers();`" but this time I have "`TypeError: handler.replaceMarkers is not a function`".

I am new to Javascript and to Rails, but I want to improve my knowledge and I really need to go on with the rest of this web app. I have been looking for a solution everywhere on the internet but in vain.

[Live website here](http://thawing-chamber-1586.herokuapp.com/)

Please, could someone tell me how I could do that and what I am doing wrong?

MANY thanks in advance,

Céline

> zones_controller.rb

```
def search
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html.none do
      search_params = params[:zone][:search]
         coordinates = Geocoder.coordinates(search_params).join(",")
         @zones = Zone.search(
           "", { "aroundLatLng" => coordinates, 
                  "aroundRadius" => 500000  #Searches around 500 km
                })
         if coordinates.nil?
           @zones = Zone.search(params[:search])
         elsif @zones.empty?
           @zones = Zone.all
           flash[:error] = "No zone could be found. Please try again."
         end
       build_map(@zones)
     end

     format.js
   end
end

def build_map(array)
  @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(array) do |zone, marker|
    marker.lat zone.latitude
    marker.lng zone.longitude
    marker.json({ title: zone.description, id: zone.id })
    marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/zones/map_box", locals: { zone: zone })
  end
end
```

> search.html.erb

```
    <div id="map" style='width: 100%; height: 700px;'>
</div>
  <!-- Beginning Google maps -->

<script type="text/javascript" id="map_script">
   $(document).ready(function() {
     <%= render 'googlemap', hash: @hash %>
   }); // Document ready
</script>
```

> _googlemap.erb

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  }, internal: {id: 'map'}
}, function(){
  markers_json = <%= raw hash.to_json %>;
  markers = _.map(markers_json, function(marker_json){

    marker = handler.addMarker(marker_json);
    handler.getMap().setZoom(4);

    _.extend(marker, marker_json);

    marker.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: marker.infowindow
    });

    return marker;
  });

  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
});
```

> search.js.erb

```
$('#map_script').replaceWith("<%= render 'googlemap', hash: @hash %>");
```

Comment: Hi Celine. I am working through a somewhat similar problem; I appreciate both your question and the answers you've gotten. I was wondering if you could share what your form looks like. Also, when you initially load the search page, nothing is being sent to the controller so the zones is therefore empty; do you set a default? I am trying to use the  view page to get the user's location via geolocatoin, then send that info back to the controller to get all the markers close by, but I'm not sure how since the order of information flow is not traditional. Your page looks really great, by the way.

Comment: Hello,
[You can find my form here](http://pastie.org/9991159). This form is in index.html.erb and sends a request to /search with params corresponding to the search so it is never empty.
You can get the user's location (using IP geocoding with [Geokit for example](https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails) ), then get all the markers close by and send them to the view.

Comment: This it work me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37803378/gmaps4rails-update-dynamically-the-markers-from-the-database-on-the-map-withou

Comment: This it work me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37803378/gmaps4rails-update-dynamically-the-markers-from-the-database-on-the-map-withou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just update the map with the new markers? Meaning, instead of re-rendering the whole map after each search, just update the markers on the existing map by removing all markers and adding the new ones.

I haven't verified the method, but I guess it should work and be more efficient:

Create a `app/assets/javascript/map.js` file. You can store your map-related functions there. Create a function to update your map's markers in this file:

> map.js

```
(function() {
  /* __markers will hold a reference to all markers currently shown
     on the map, as GMaps4Rails won't do it for you.
     This won't pollute the global window object because we're nested
     in a "self-executed" anonymous function */
  var __markers;

  function updateMarkers(map, markersData) 
  {
    // Remove current markers
    map.removeMarkers(__markers);

    // Add each marker to the map according to received data
    __markers = _.map(markersData, function(markerJSON) {
      marker = map.addMarker(markerJSON);
      map.getMap().setZoom(4); // Not sure this should be in this iterator!

      _.extend(marker, markerJSON);

      marker.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: marker.infowindow
      });

      return marker;
    });

    map.bounds.extendWith(__markers);
    map.fitMapToBounds();
  };

  // "Publish" our method on window. You should probably have your own namespace
  window.updateMarkers = updateMarkers;
})();
```

This function can be used to initialize your map and to update it. As you will not (if my answer satisfies you) render the map twice, you can delete `_google_map.erb` and put its content back into `search.html.erb`, but using the function we've just created:

> search.html.erb

```
    <div id="map" style='width: 100%; height: 700px;'>
</div>
  <!-- Beginning Google maps -->

<script type="text/javascript" id="map_script">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       mapHandler = Gmaps.build('Google');
       mapHandler.buildMap({ provider: {
           disableDefaultUI: true,
           mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
         }, internal: {id: 'map'}
       }, function(){
         var markersData = <%= raw @hash.to_json %>;
         updateMarkers(mapHandler, markersData);
       });
   }); // Document ready
</script>
```

Please **don't forget the var keyword** when declaring variables, otherwise they will end up being globals, and that's bad ^^
Note that I have deliberately left `mapHandler` as a global variable: you will need access to your handler to update markers later when someone uses the search. This is probably not an ideal thing to do, but this question is not about refactoring your code so let's keep it this way.

So now my solution brings you a map that initializes with the given markers on page load. In other words, nothing has changed!

However you're now allowed to reuse this `updateMarkers` function to change the markers displayed on your map. That's what you `search.js.erb` script should do:

> search.js.erb

```
(function() {
  var markersData = <%= raw @hash.to_json %>;
  updateMarkers(mapHandler, markersData);
})();
```

That's it! Hopefully it'll take you to the next step of your project :)

Comment: Hi Olivier. Thanks for answering! Your answer works very well, thanks!! There is only a minor typo mistake in your map.js. It's `map` not `handler`. The only problem I have concerns the zoom. At the beginning it sets correctly (conforming to the answers) but at the second call (i.e. using ajax and not html) it shows France and doesn't zoom in. But I'll figure this out by myself. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Olivier and Celine, thanks for posting this question and the answer. I am trying something similar, and your answers have been very useful for me! I too am new to rails and especially javascript. I have implemented most of the solution but I have one thing I'd like to fix, which is this: When I pan and zoom, I am constantly resubmitting the search to remove/add markers as necessary. This works, but if it turns out the same markers are already on screen, I don't want to remove and redraw the same markers. How might I test existing __markers against the new @hash that is returned from search?

Comment: This is what i've tried but doesn't work: I created a new variable called "var __oldHash" right underneath var __markers. I then did a _.isEqual(__oldHash, markersData) to see if they were the same, and if they weren't, then it'd go through the whole UpdateMarkers function, and at the end I'd set __oldHash = markersData.slice(0) . For whatever reason, if I check the isEqual right after the assignment, then of course it's True. But at the top, even when I think they should be the same, it's always false....

Comment: I'm not sure why __markers will hold a reference to all the markers on the map, but my __oldHash, which is declared at the same place, is empty everytime the function gets called.... I would test against the __markers itself, but I can't seem to do it since I'd have to rebuild the map while creating __newMarkers in order to check against it thus defeating the purpose...

Comment: hey @kindofgreat, I think you should start your own question for this, so that you can paste code and better explain your situation ;)

Comment: @Olivier, I'll do that if I can't figure it out tonight :) Was hoping maybe Celine had come across a similar situation and knew the answer... First thing I need to do is learn to use the javascript debugging tool in Chrome because littering my code with alerts is ridiculous!

Comment: @OlivierLance I spent a good amount of time trying to work it through without avail! If you have a minute, I'd appreciate if you looked at my question; I bet you'd see the problem in a second: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28864324/google-maps-for-rails-updating-markers-via-ajax-only-when-search-result-change

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same thing but instead of updating the `marker` you should include the map in the `partial/placeholder` and then update it ...

**for example, this is the view which is displaying the map...i will update this view/placeholder with latest map and markers**

```
<div id="map_users_index">
<div id="map" class="map" style="height:relative;">
</div>
```

**in users_controller.rb**

```
   ##take index action or any other action 
    def index
    ##do your stuff and get more users
         respond_to do |format|
           format.html 
           format.js
         end
    end
```

**in index.js.erb**

```
##update the placeholder/partial with new map with new markers

$("#map_users_index").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'index')) %>");
```

I HAVE MY OWN WORKING CODE...[HERE](http://quabr.com/24832979/show-multiple-markers-on-google-maps-dynamically-using-resultset-returned-rails)

Comment: Hello Milind,
So I moved the div `map_container` to the partial but the map doesn't want to initialize now. I don't understand because @hash is giving the right answer... Do I need to move the javascript in the index? But how can I change my markers if the javascript is in the index?

Comment: i have updated the answer with the code .please check it out.hope it will help you out :)...@CélineMartinetSanchez