# Google Maps For Rails - updating markers via ajax only when search result changes

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, gmaps4rails

I have been working through writing a small app with a lot of help from stackoverflow. The basic premise is simple, and I've seen this sort of functionality all over the web: I am trying to plot a list of locations onto a searchable/pannable google map. The locations are stored on the backend, and the controller feeds these locations to the view. AJAX is involved because I don't want to reload the entire page. Here are the scenarios: a) User searches for a location via zipcode => map loads new location, a search get is sent to server and map loads any markers if there are any within set radius, map sets a default zoom level; b) User pans/zooms around => map stays wherever the user has left it, a search with the viewport bounding box is sent to the server and the results are mapped. The map will default to Seattle on initial load and the first thing it tries is to geolocate the user...

Using the gmaps4ails wiki and mostly a modified version of the answer from this question: [Google Maps for Rails - update markers with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28456641/google-maps-for-rails-update-markers-with-ajax)  I have gotten very close. It works, actually, just with a hitch. Here is what it looks like:

#### sightings_controller.rb

```
  def search
    if params[:lat]
      @ll = [params[:lat].to_f, params[:lng].to_f]
      @sightings = Sighting.within(5, origin: @ll).order('created_at DESC')
      @remap = true
    elsif search_params = params[:zipcode]
      geocode = Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.geocode(search_params)
      @ll = [geocode.lat, geocode.lng]
      @sightings = Sighting.within(5, origin: @ll).order('created_at DESC')
      @remap = true
    elsif params[:bounds]
      boundarray = params[:bounds].split(',')
      bounds = [[boundarray[0].to_f, boundarray[1].to_f], [boundarray[2].to_f, boundarray[3].to_f]]
      @ll = [params[:center].split(',')[0].to_f, params[:center].split(',')[1].to_f]
      @sightings = Sighting.in_bounds(bounds, origin: @ll).order('created_at DESC')
      @remap = false
    else
      search_params = '98101'
      geocode = Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.geocode(search_params)
      @ll = [geocode.lat, geocode.lng]
      @sightings = Sighting.within(5, origin: @ll).order('created_at DESC')
      @remap = true
    end
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@sightings) do |sighting, marker|
      marker.lat sighting.latitude
      marker.lng sighting.longitude
      marker.name sighting.title
      marker.infowindow view_context.link_to("sighting", sighting)
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

#### search.html.haml

```
= form_tag search_sightings_path, method: "get", id: "zipform", role: "form", remote: true do
  = text_field_tag :zipcode, params[:zipcode], size: 5, maxlength: 5, placeholder: "zipcode", id: "zipsearch"
  = button_tag "Search", name: "button"
  %input{type: "button", value: "Current Location", onclick: "getUserLocation()"}
#locationData

.sightings_map_container
 .sightings_map_canvas#sightings_map_canvas
   #sightings_container

- content_for :javascript do
  %script{src: "//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry", type: "text/javascript"}
  %script{src: "//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js", type: "text/javascript"}

  :javascript
    function getUserLocation() {
      //check if the geolocation object is supported, if so get position
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setLocation);
      }
      else {
        document.getElementById("locationData").innerHTML = "Sorry - your browser doesn't support geolocation!";
      }
    }

    function setLocation(position) {
      //build text string including co-ordinate data passed in parameter
      var displayText = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + ", Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;

      //display the string for demonstration
      document.getElementById("locationData").innerHTML = displayText;
      //submit the lat/lng coordinates of current location
      $.get('/sightings/search.js',{lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude});
    }
    // build maps via Gmaps4rails
    handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    handler.buildMap({
      provider: {
      },
      internal: {
      id: 'sightings_map_canvas'
      }
    },

    function() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setLocation);
      }

      var json_array = #{raw @hash.to_json};
      var latlng = #{raw @ll};

      resetMarkers(handler, json_array);
      resetMap(handler, latlng);

      // listen for pan/zoom and submit new coordinates
      (function gmaps4rails_callback() {
        google.maps.event.addListener(handler.getMap(), 'idle', function() {
          var bounds = handler.getMap().getBounds().toUrlValue();
          var center = handler.getMap().getCenter().toUrlValue();
          $.get('/sightings/search.js',{bounds: bounds, center: center, old_hash: #{raw @hash.to_json}});
        })
      })();
    });
```

#### search.js.erb

```
(function() {
  var json_array = <%= raw @hash.to_json %>;
  if (<%= @remap %>) {
    var latlng = <%= raw @ll %>;
    resetMarkers(handler, json_array);
    resetMap(handler, latlng);
  }
  else {
    resetMarkers(handler, json_array);
  }
})();
```

#### map.js

```
(function() {

  function createSidebarLi(json) {
    return ("<li><a>" + json.name + "</a></li>");
  };

  function bindLiToMarker($li, marker) {
    $li.on('click', function() {
      handler.getMap().setZoom(18);
      marker.setMap(handler.getMap()); //because clusterer removes map property from marker
      google.maps.event.trigger(marker.getServiceObject(), 'click');
    })
  };

  function createSidebar(json_array) {
    _.each(json_array, function(json) {
      var $li = $( createSidebarLi(json) );
      $li.appendTo('#sightings_container');
      bindLiToMarker($li, json.marker);
    });
  };

  function clearSidebar() {
    $('#sightings_container').empty();
  };

  function clearZipcode() {
    $('#zipform')[0].reset();
  };

  /* __markers will hold a reference to all markers currently shown
  on the map, as GMaps4Rails won't do it for you.
  This won't pollute the global window object because we're nested
  in a "self-executed" anonymous function */

  var __markers;

  function resetMarkers(handler, json_array) {
    handler.removeMarkers(__markers);
    clearSidebar();
    clearZipcode();
    if (json_array.length > 0) {
      __markers = handler.addMarkers(json_array);
      _.each(json_array, function(json, index){
        json.marker = __markers[index];
      });
      createSidebar(json_array);
    }
  };

  function resetMap(handler, latlng) {
    handler.bounds.extendWith(__markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
    handler.getMap().setZoom(12);
    handler.map.centerOn({
      lat: latlng[0],
      lng: latlng[1]
    });
  }

// "Publish" our method on window. You should probably have your own namespace
  window.resetMarkers = resetMarkers;
  window.resetMap = resetMap;

})();
```

Here's the problem, and it is as much to do with this specific example as my seeming misunderstanding of how javascript (I'm new to it) variables work. When the user pans and zooms, but the search result is the same, I would prefer NOT to call the "resetMarkers" function, but would rather just leave the map alone. The map will currently always resetMarkers/sidebar/etc and this causes a little bit of a flicker of markers on the screen.

I've tried several different versions of this, but doesn't work. In map.js:

```
var __markers;
var __oldmarkers;
function resetMarkers(handler, json_array) {
  if(!(_.isEqual(__oldmarkers, __markers))) {
    handler.removeMarkers(__markers);
    clearSidebar();
    clearZipcode();
    if (json_array.length > 0) {
      __markers = handler.addMarkers(json_array);
      _.each(json_array, function(json, index){
        json.marker = __markers[index];
      });
      createSidebar(json_array);
    }
    __oldmarkers = __markers.slice(0);
  }
};
```

Since __markers seems to hold its value through the life of the page (we use it to remove the old markers before we set new ones), I thought I could simply create another variable to check against it. However, it's always false even when I think it should be true.

Another thing I've tried is to resubmit the old hash as a parameter with every search request and then set a flag, but this seems complicated, and the string/hash/array manipulation got so confusing I gave up. I don't really think this would be the best approach, but perhaps I should do it that way?

Or, is there something I am missing completely and should be doing instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in comparing both lists of markers to decide whether you should update or not.

The thing is, although `_.isEqual(__oldmarkers, __markers)` does perform a deep comparison, there might be things in Marker instances within your list that change even for identical points (an id, timestamps, ...).
Or perhaps it's simply because at the start, both `__markers` and `__oldMarkers` are `null`, thus equal, meaning you never get inside the `if`block.

Anyway, I think deep comparison here could become too costly. What I'd do instead, is compare things that are comparable easily, like the flat list of coordinates for each set of markers.

Something like this:

```
var __markers, __coordinates = [];
function resetMarkers(handler, json_array) 
{
  var coordinates = _.map(json_array, function(marker) {
    return String(marker.lat) + ',' + String(marker.lng);
  });

  if(_.isEqual(__coordinates.sort(), coordinates.sort()))
  {
    handler.removeMarkers(__markers);
    clearSidebar();
    clearZipcode();
    if (json_array.length > 0) 
    {
      __markers = handler.addMarkers(json_array);
      _.each(json_array, function(json, index){
        json.marker = __markers[index];
      });
      createSidebar(json_array);
    }
    __coordinates = coordinates;
  }
};
```

Here `__coordinates` and `coordinates` are just flat arrays of String, which should be compared quickly and give you the expected results.
In ordered to be compared using `_.isEqual`, both arrays are sorted beforehand.

*NB: Old code used _.difference but that wasn't correct (see discussion in comments)*
*(Note that I'm using `_.difference` though, probably more costly than `_.isEqual` but with the bonus of being independent of the returned markers order.)*

edit: Oh and of course you can stop sending that "oldHash" in the search query params now ;)

Comment: Thanks Olivier! Your answer looked good, and made sense, but didn't work. It took me a while to figure out why! First there was a typo, should be marker.lat and marker.lng, but this is not your fault and when I figured it out, I thought I was done. But i was not!

Comment: After looking at it a long time while being very confused, I finally figured out that __.difference was the problem.   _.difference([1], null) = 1 (length = 1) BUT _.difference(null,[1]) = [blank] (length = 0). So turns out, I need to check both: if((_.difference(coordinates, __coordinates).length > 0) || (_.difference(__coordinates, coordinates).length > 0))    So though difference has the bonus of being array element order independent, difference itself is parameter order dependent! Tomorrow I will think about if there's a cheaper comparison. Thank you Olivier for your help pointing the way!

Comment: Hmm I just tried and got:
`_.difference([1], null) => [1]` and  `_.difference(null, [1]) => [1]`

I bet you're using underscore.js, whereas I personally prefer and use lodash, which is a more performant drop-in replacement for underscore. You could try using it instead :)

Comment: Ah yes, I'm using underscore. I'll try lodash! Though, if _.difference is different, then they're not drop-in replacements for each other!

Comment: Using lodash now, and the 'null' example is definitely different. This is important for the loop because when the page is first loaded, __coordinates will be null, so I need to put the markers initially. However, I still need to check both (_.difference(__coordinates, coordinates)) and (_.difference(coordinates, __coordinates)) because both underscore and lo-dash returns values in the second array that is not in the first. For example, _.difference([1,2,3],[1] = [2, 3], but _.difference([1], [1,2,3]) = null . So I need to check both conditions in case markers get added or subtracted.

Comment: Ah, yeah ok I must have been a bit too sleepy when reading you the first time :) well then maybe the best would be to sort _coordinates and simply use isEqual? ^^

Comment: Yeah. I think I've decided to:first set var __coordinates = [], and then check for coordinates.sort().toString() != __coordinates.sort().toString()  . This seems to work. Olivier, I already marked your answer as correct, but if you could edit your answer to use one of these that work, it could help out someone who has a similar question. Thanks for all your help.