# Adding google map markers dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, google-maps-api-3

Here is the workflow I would like the website to work like:

1. a map is loaded when the page is loaded
2. users can filter the data and extract relevant objects, which all contain lat and lon attributes, from the database
3. add one marker to that map for each object

So now I can add the markers when the page is refreshed. However I wanted to incorporate AJAX into my page and still adding markers properly.

Now I have function showPosition() to add markers in the index.html.erb file and enclose that with `< script type="text/javascript">  < script>`

I was trying to call this function in my refresh.js.erb file

Is it the right approach? If not what should I do?

Comment: Sorry I think I have found solution here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28456641/google-maps-for-rails-update-markers-with-ajax

Comment: Actually it looks like the approach above is different from mine and I can't get that working

Comment: I think you should add `javascript` and `jquery` to the tags, to get better responses. If you want it dynamically, it's more a question of those than rails :)

Comment: Emil, you have any thought on how to do it?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Javascript google maps docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/)? or the [ruby ones](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/start/get_started? Also Javascript is a client side language where Ruby is a server side language.

Comment: I have. indeed it's working if I don't try to use AJAX, by which i avoid refreshing the page everytime I make a new search. However I just can't make it work with AJAX