# google map reload marker refreshes the zoom

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I have been following the gmaps4rails gem and i was able to reload the marker with setinterval function. the problem i'm facing is after each interval the map goes back to original, i.e if i'm zoomed in it goes back to normal.

This is the code

```
success: (data, jqxhr, status) ->
  console.log('data.bookings', data)
  $('#multi_markers').removeClass('hidden')
  $('.empty_booking_text').removeClass('hidden')
  $('#sidebar_container').html('Please click any booking marker on the map')
  markers_from_api = data.bookings
  handler = Gmaps.build('Google')
  settings = {
    internal: {
      id: 'multi_markers'
    },
    provider:{
      styles: mapStyles
    }
  }
  handler.buildMap settings, ->
    markers = handler.addMarkers(markers_from_api)
    _.each markers,(marker, j) ->
      google.maps.event.addListener marker.serviceObject, 'click', (object) ->
        console.log marker.serviceObject.position.lng()
        render_marker_data markers_from_api[j].id
        return
    handler.bounds.extendWith markers
    handler.fitMapToBounds()
  setInterval () ->
    $ -> update_marker_data(handler)
  , 10000
```

every 10 sec i update the marker

```
update_marker_data = (handler) ->
  markers = []
  $.ajax '/technician_locations/current_location',
    type: 'GET'
    success: (data, jqxhr, status) ->
      # handler.removeMarkers()
      console.log(data)
      tech_markers_from_api = data.technician_locations
      tech_markers = handler.addMarkers(tech_markers_from_api)
      _.each tech_markers,(marker, j) ->
        markers.push(marker)
        # google.maps.event.addListener marker.serviceObject, 'click', (object) ->
        #   render_marker_data tech_markers_from_api[j].id
        #   return
      # handler.bounds.extendWith tech_markers
      setInterval () ->
        $ -> remove_marker(markers)
      , 9000
      handler.fitMapToBounds()
```

Comment: What exactly does `fitMapToBounds` do? As far as I understand, it will zoom and/or center the map so that _all_ markers are visible inside the viewport, which seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37803378/gmaps4rails-update-dynamically-the-markers-from-the-database-on-the-map-withou) for the code sample. You just need to replace the markers with x interval using [AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28456641/google-maps-for-rails-update-markers-with-ajax).

```
<script>
    handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
        handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
           markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
           handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
           $( document ).ready(function() {         
            setInterval(function(){
                $(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                      type:"GET",
                      url:"/path_to_controller_action",
                      dataType:"json",
                      data: {some_id:1},
                      success:function(result){                     
                        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                          markers[i].setMap(null);
                          handler.removeMarkers(markers);
                        }
                        markers = [];
                        markers = handler.addMarkers(result);
                        handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);                         
                      }
                    })
                });
               }, 10000);
            handler.fitMapToBounds();
            handler.getMap().setZoom(17);     
            });             
        });
</script>
```